# Place plain text next to f.label using HAML (Rails 3.2 + Bootstrap + HAML)

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I am making a form in HAML and having trouble aligning elements next to each other. I know this is a common issue with many questions on SO but I haven't found an answer yet that fixed my problem. This is my code:

```
  .form-group.odd
    .row
      .col-sm-12
        = f.label :university_college, 'College(s)'
        Where did you go to school?
```

I am trying to get "Where did you go to school?" to appear in the view right next to the text of the form label. I thought that putting it right under the other line should make it appear side-by-side but that's not working. The text of the question appears under the `f.label` text. Here is the HTML that is being produced:

```
 <div class='form-group odd'>
   <div class='row'>
     <div class='col-sm-12'>
       <label for="worker_university_college">College(s)</label>
         Test
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I've also tried this:

```
  .form-group.odd
    .row
      .col-sm-12
        = f.label :university_college, 'College(s)' + 'Where did you go to school?'
```

...but that is causing the question, which I want to be plain text without bold weight, to be styled with the bold weight of the `f.label` text.

I have also toyed with different variations of the whitespace removers from the HAML documentation but haven't been able to make it work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: added the HTML produced by my original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be 100% certain of this without seeing your markup, but it sounds like your `label` elements are being styled with `block` layout.

Your second example is including the "Where did you go to school?" text inside the `label` tag, which is not what you want, as you say.

Instead, use the HAML from your first example, and add CSS which changes the `display` attribute of the `label` tags to `inline`.

Comment: I tried this two different ways but the sentence is still appearing under the label. See edited post for the code I used

Comment: I will try to post the HTML that I'm getting, too

Comment: Having played around with the HTML in the Chrome inspector a little, I'm now convinced that you're right and I'm just not coding the style correctly with HAML